# Tkinter using widget.after(30000, lambda: showFirstScreen()

Tags: python, user-interface, time, tkinter, reset

I have a GUI with alot of buttons/widgets. I want that if 30 secs passes and the user didnt hit anything on the GUI that it will automaticly go back to the first screen.

I added this between root = Tk() and root.mainloop()

```
root.after(30000, lambda: showFirstScreen())
```

This line will go to my first screen after 30 seconds even if you hit the screen. So there is no counter that resets after hitting a button/widget.

I try'd to add it to a specific button on a other window so:

```
button13.after(30000, lambda: showFirstScreen())
```

If I reach the page with the button it will move to the main window after 30 seconds. But If I go back to the button it wont repeat the action above.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to check if the user interacts with widgets, something like,

```
def showFirstScreen(buttons_pressed):
    if buttons_pressed==True:
        ...code to go to first screen...
```

Use the `buttons_pressed` variable inside all your buttons' call methods to check if the user has used any button.

If you want to add `after()` to a button on another window, you can use a separate function,

```
button13_onPress():
    if buttons_pressed==True:
        root.after(30000, lambda: showFirstScreen())
```